# Trying to create a custom method using prototype property but i get Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, regex, methods, replace, prototype

So I'm messing around with JS trying to create a method which adds CSS style to elements without removing currently applied style:

```
// ==================================================================================================
// this method adds style to an element using CSS inline syntax without removing unaltered CSS styles
// ==================================================================================================
Element.prototype.cssStyle = function (style)
{
    let styleChars = style.split(''); // split each character of the style arg as an item in an array
    let positions = [];
    for(let i=0; i<styleChars.length; i++){
        if(styleChars[i] === '-'){
            positions.push(i+1);
        };
    };
    positions.forEach(function (position){ // for each match
        styleChars.splice(position, 1, style[position].toUpperCase()); // make that character uppercase
    });
    styleChars.splice(0, 0, '[["'); // add a "[[" item on the first position
    styleChars.splice(styleChars.length, 0, '"]]'); //add a "[[" on the last position
    style = styleChars.join('') // join back the array into a string
    style = style.replace(/:/g, "\",\"").replace(/;/g, "\"],[\"").replace(/-/g, ""); // replace some character in order to make the string look like an array
    style = JSON.parse(style); // parse the string into an array
    for(let i=0; i<style.length; i++){ // for each item in the array
        let property = style[i][0].replace(/ */, ""); // remove some characters which might inhibit normal execution
        let value = style[i][1].replace(/;/, "").replace(/ */, ""); //remove some characters which might inhibit normal execution
        this.style[property] = value // change style of the element
    };
    return this.getAttribute('style'); //return all inline CSS styles
}
```

so if I try to style an element like this:

```js
Element.cssStyle('background-color: white; color: #000')
```

It works as expected, but if I add a `;` at the end of the parameter string I get this

```js
Element.cssStyle('background-color: white; color: #000;')
```

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined'
```

Even though I don't see any apparent issues with the replace method, what could it be?

Replacing whitespace at that exact line works just fine, but trying to replace `;` I get that error.

Also how badly written is my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Wow... I think your "MESSing around with JS" intro is pretty accurate here :) You're overthinking and overcomplicating. You should never try to build a JSON string yourself. There will never be an excuse for this. You're giving yourself  (and your futureself, as someone who needs to maintain this code in 5 years) a hard time for no reason

Comment: Thanks for the comment. with my limited knowledge of JavaScript this is all i could come up with :(.  any suggestions or alternative solutions to this will be appreciated.

Comment: Sure, I'm trying to figure out what this does (because that does make things harder to read). I just wanted you to get this point and remember it in the future. I've learned it the hard way in the past, and I would have loved to get this advice earlier as a beginner. I'll probably post an answer in a couple of minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example:

```js
Element.prototype.cssStyle = function(styleStr) {
  let styles = styleStr.split(';')
  styles.forEach(style => {
    if (!style.trim()) return;

    let name = style.split(':')[0].trim();
    let value = style.split(':')[1].trim();
    this.style[name] = value;
  })

  return this.getAttribute('style'); //return all inline CSS styles
}

let testEl = document.getElementById("test")
console.log(testEl.cssStyle("color: white; background-color: black;"))
```

```html
<p id="test">This is a test paragraph</p>
```

A few things to note:

- This does NOT parse all CSS but I believe it works for your examples.
- It is NOT recommended to modify the prototype of an object because if you are using someone else's code along with yours you might run into problems of overwriting each other's modifications.

The code works by splitting the string into each style segment and then it loops over those with `forEach` and changes the style of the element using `this.style`

Documentation:

- [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`String.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)
- [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: My god, this proves how much i suck at JS still. Thank you, it's simple, concise, and definitely not over-complicated like mine. Thank you! Which CSS does it not parse if you would be so kind?

Comment: @neophoriac It can't parse [selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp) or any other more complicated feature of css.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```js
Element.prototype.cssStyle = function(str) {
  // Split styles
  const styles = str.split(';');
  // For each of them
  for (let style of styles) {
    // Get the property and value without extra spaces (using trim)
    const [property, value] = style.split(':').map(s => s.trim());
    // If none of them is empty
    if (property.length && value.length) {
      const camelCaseProperty = kebakCaseToCamelCase(property);
      this.style[camelCaseProperty] = value;
    }
  }

  return this.getAttribute('style');
};

function kebakCaseToCamelCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/-(.)/g, (match, capture) => capture.toUpperCase());
}

document.querySelector('span')
  .cssStyle('display: block; background-color: red; color: white;');
```

```html
<span>Hello world</span>
```

but as @anbcodes proved it in his answer, I think you can even skip the camel case conversion

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I had no idea you can use split like that, neither about trim. I feel bad about myself for sure. Although i'll give the best answer to anbcodes, for making it look so easy and for bypassing the case conversion altogether.  Also a newbie like me still don't know about map() . And did you also use destructuring? i still don't know about that either :( anyway thanks again

Comment: Don't feel bad! We're all learning. And see? You already know that what I used here is destructuring even though I didn't mention it! Now all you need to do is look it up on Google and SO to learn more about it if you want to use it